# EC2 instance connect : There was a problem setting up the instance connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I launched a new Amazon Linux 2 instance. I tried connecting to the instance via the EC2 instance connect option under the `Connect` -> `EC2 Instance Connect (browser-based SSH connection)` option in the Management Console. I get the error:

```
There was a problem setting up the instance connection
An internal error has occurred within the remote server, and the connection has been terminated.
If this instance has just started up, try again in a minute or two.
```

The SSH port is open to the world(0.0.0.0/0). I am able to connect to EC2 instance with the SSH key configured via my local machines terminal but instance connect from the browser is not working.

Comment: Have you tried SSH via terminal?

Comment: Yes, Working. But was really keen on accessing it via the console from he browser.

Comment: you cant, aws team developed only half of the platform, you need to do the other half

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In order to connect to your instance with "EC2 Instance Connect (browser-based SSH connection)" you need to install *ec2-instance-connect* to your AMI.

Try connecting to your instance via "A standalone SSH client" (eg. putty) and installing it with a command:

```
sudo yum install ec2-instance-connect
```

or (for Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install ec2-instance-connect
```

To me this worked, and I could then easily access my instance via browser next time.

The more detailed explanation is found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html

Comment: Putting these in User Data `#!/bin/bash` [next line] `yum update -y` [next line] `yum install -y ec2-instance-connect` should allow you to not even need Putty / other tools.

Comment: I installed successfully `ec2-instance-connect` but still same error message

Comment: installed using ```sudo apt-get install ec2-instance-connect``` , but the same problem persists.

Comment: I have to open ssh to 0.0.0.0/0. If I set inbound rule ssh from my IP only, it doesn't work.

Comment: nothing works on aws

Comment: @ReyanshKharga related: 
> instead of accepting a connection from "My IP", the security group on the EC2 instance should allow inbound connections from the EC2 Instance Connect service. \ 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56917634/amazon-ec2-instance-connect-for-ssh-security-group

Answer (score 10):

Mostly this happens when you try to enable the ufw. So, follow the below actions to gain access again over SSH:

1. Go to your AWS EC2 console
2. Select your instance that is not able to connect
3. Stop your instance
4. Go to Actions -> Instance Settings -> Edit User Data
5. Add this user data in user data.

> ```
> Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
> MIME-Version: 1.0
> --//
> Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
> MIME-Version: 1.0
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
> Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"
> #cloud-config
> cloud_final_modules:
> - [scripts-user, always]
> --//
> Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
> MIME-Version: 1.0
> Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
> Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"
> #!/bin/bash
> ufw disable
> iptables -L
> iptables -F
> --//
> ```

6. Save this and restart instance.
7. Hopefully now you'll be able to connect with SSH.

Comment: Thanks this save our lot's of work actually we forgot to enable port 22 in ubuntu firewall.

Comment: I feel glad that my answer helped you. @ManojThapliyal

Comment: This worked for me as well. Once I got access to the instance, I re-enabled the firewall after opening up needed ports.

Comment: I frgot to enable port 22 in ubuntu firewall too. Saved my time.

Answer (score 3):

Almost every time I've tried to use the SSH via Browser for EC2 never worked, like maybe 1-2 times, try to do it from terminal instead

Comment: SSH via terminal is working. I was learning AWS and exploring around the console. The convinience of accessing instance from browser for small task is really good.

Comment: I know exactly what you mean, I have to use ec2 for my daily tasks and sometimes all I need is to do something quick and if that option was working that would be awesome but it seems that's not the case and it's not something recent.

On the other hand Google Cloud Platform does this perfect, is the best thing I have seen so far and I think this is exactly what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that AMI is of Amazon Linux 2 type as it comes bundled with necessary softwares.
Recently there is a change in AMI selection window where Ubuntu is pre-selected.

Comment: Not quite true. Browser instance connect to Ubuntu works fine too. Besides other stuff, you need to make sure to allow ssh from all IPs (0.0.0.0/0).

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-connect-set-up.html

1. Install EC2 Instance Connect package
   You WILL need to install EC2 Instance Connect. You can only install EC2 Instance Connect on the following Linux distributions:
   Amazon Linux 2 (any version)
   Ubuntu 16.04 and above

EC2 Instance Connect is installed on the following distros by default:

- Amazon Linux 2 2.0.20190618 or later
- Ubuntu 20.04 or later

sudo yum install ec2-instance-connect

You should see four new scripts in the /opt/aws/bin/ folder:

- eic_curl_authorized_keys
- eic_harvest_hostkeys
- eic_parse_authorized_keys
- eic_run_authorized_keys

Installing the EC2 Instance Connect package will make changes to your /etc/ssh/sshd_config file.

Instance Connect was successfully installed if the **AuthorizedKeysCommand** and **AuthorizedKeysCommandUser** lines in the /etc/ssh/sshd_config file contain the following values:

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /opt/aws/bin/eic_run_authorized_keys %u %f    
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser ec2-instance-connect 

AuthorizedKeysCommand sets the eic_run_authorized_keys script to look up the keys from the instance metadata 
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser sets the system user as ec2-instance-connect
```

NOTE: If you configured the AuthorizedKeysCommand and AuthorizedKeysCommandUser settings for SSH authentication, the EC2 Instance Connect installation will not update them. As a result, you cannot use Instance Connect

2. Security Groups associated with the instance you want to connect to MUST have EC2 Instance Connect service IP range listed. As well as the IP address or range from the connecting user(s) - example their home, work or wherever.

Ensure that the security group associated with your instance allows inbound SSH traffic from the IP address range for this service. You will need to download or open this file in a browser: https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json - so that you can find the IP address range. To identify the address range, look for the subset for EC2 Instance Connect, using EC2_INSTANCE_CONNECT as the service value - find your region. Here is an example:

```
   {
      "ip_prefix": "18.206.107.24/29",
      "region": "us-east-1",
      "service": "EC2_INSTANCE_CONNECT",
      "network_border_group": "us-east-1"
    }
```

3. Configure AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) policies or permissions

The user that is connecting using Instance connect needs the EC2InstanceConnect policy provided by AWS. Though that might be a little to open for your needs to so you may need to restrict it with a more narrow policy of your own instead. For example:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2-instance-connect:SendSSHPublicKey",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:ec2:region:account-id:instance/i-1234567890abcdef0",
            "arn:aws:ec2:region:account-id:instance/i-0598c7d356eba48d7"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:osuser": "ami-username"
            }
        }
      },
      {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "ec2:DescribeInstances",
        "Resource": "*"
      }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a security group that automatically blocks unknown SSH connections then the browser based connection won't work. Therefore you need to add inbound SSH connections from everywhere. This is more likely to be the issue as ec2-instance-connect will come with most recent EC2 installations.

Answer (score 1):

For me the issue was that traffic was not enabled on port 22. I had to enable traffic on port 22. I am using terraform to define my aws_security_group, here is my terraform to allow traffic on port 22:

```
resource "aws_security_group" "instance" {
  name = "terraform-example-instance"

  # Allow SSH traffic on port 22
  ingress {
    from_port   = 22
    to_port     = 22
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using EC2 Instance Connect to connect to the instance's public IP address, ensure that you've launched the instance into a public subnet. That is, a subnet with a default route to an Internet Gateway in your VPC. The traffic from EC2 Instance Connect will not be able to reach your instance if the instance is in a private subnet.